# How to add module-info to generated classes?

Tags: java, maven, module

I use multiple annotation processors to generate code in my project and now plan to migrate it to java 11.

How do I make maven generate or copy a module-info.java to the target directory?

Comment: You create the `module-info.java` by hand. There is not much in it.

Comment: Create the `module-info.java` file in `src/main/java` and the rest should work ...

Comment: @JohannesKuhn i cannot create it by hand since the generated sources are recreated every build under target/generated-souces

Comment: Yeah, and module-info.java is not generated. It should go with the other source code.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn you do know that generated != compiled? The sources i'm talking about are generated by an annotation processor. I am unable to manually add files to that folder since the whole folder is generated at compile time

Comment: Yeah. That's why you don't add it to the generated source files, and instead add it to the regular source files. (Yes, an annotation processor COULD generate it... but that is not worth the effort.)

Comment: @JohannesKuhn the folder that needs the module-info is being generated at compile time in its entirety. adding a module-info to the folder with the normal sources does not influence the generated one. this is exactly the problem im trying to solve

Comment: "adding a module-info to the folder with the normal sources does not influence the generated one" This is wrong. Or should be wrong. Fix your build then. (The generated sources should be compiled together with the normal classes, not independently.)